# How can we configure the Streaming Replication(master-slave) on single SAN storage in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to configure the Streaming Replication in PostgreSQL.My data directories of Primary and Standby are in same SAN storage.Is it Possible to do replication.

Comment: What would be the point?

Comment: I was planning for a DR setup.My two Primary and standby are in same Storage area.In this scenario how can we configure the Streaming replication accordingly.

Comment: If everything is on the same SAN, how do you recover when the SAN fails?

Comment: You configure it the same way as any other replication configuration. Have two Postgres servers where the masters streams the WAL files to the slave - you just need to make sure that master and slave use different data directories.

Answer (score 3):

I try to answer below, but:

**DON'T DO THIS!**

You are planning a disaster recovery setup, but when the disaster hits the shared storage (the SAN), you will stand there with no usable database.

You can do that, yes, just as @a_horse_with_no_name describes in his comment.  You have to have two separate data directories for it, the master pointing to one and the slave to the other.  Setting up the replication is the same as with completely separated machines.

Also, plan regularly taking and testing backups as part of your disaster recovery process.